# How to modify the width of v-text-field in a d-flex in vue?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm new to vue and I have two v-text-field in a flexbox. They are taking all available space of a line side by side. However, I wanna make them smaller. I have tried add a style to modify the width but it doesn't work. I guess the style is overwritten? Here is my code of template and style:

```
 <div class="selector pa-3 pt-0">
       <div class="d-flex justify-space-between align-center py-2">
        <v-text-field
          outlined
          dense
          clearable
          hide-details
          class="textbox"
        />
        <v-text-field
          outlined
          dense
          clearable
          hide-details
          class="textbox"
        />
      </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the `<style>` part

```
<style scoped>
  .selector {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 12px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .textbox {
    width: 30px;
  }
</style>
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change width with max-width it will work

```
.textbox {
    max-width: 30px ;
  }
```

[here](https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/ExENGGN) is the link of codepen